# $http.get make multiple calls sometime i.e three.

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Following code which is used to make get request but somehow it makes three call if response takes time as in my case response might take half an hour because there is a long process going on backend side.

```js
var config = {
  "withCredentials": true,
  "url": "algo",
  "method": "GET",
  "params": {
    "algo": "test"
  },
  "timeout": 30000000
}

var deferred = this.$q.defer();

this.$http(config).success(function (result) {
                    deferred.resolve(result);
                }).error(function (error, errorCode) {
                    _this.onError(error);
                    deferred.reject(new Core.Models.HttpError(error, errorCode));
                }).finally(function() {
                    console.log("finally finished gists");
                });
                return deferred.promise;
```

Comment: For starters, the $http service returns a promise so there's no reason to introduce another promise via $q.defer().  Also, the .success().error().finally() methods have been deprecated in favor of the .then() method

Comment: So when your backend takes too much time to respond, the front end calls it 3 times? Is that right?

Comment: yes cameron as it is regarding model development so it will take too much time. Any alternative or solution to overcome this.?